# How to get a numeric value from Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas data frame, `attack_probability_df`:

```
    city        date        attack probability
0   Rome      1996-02-23    0.163317
1   Rome      1996-02-24    0.219221
2   Rome      1996-02-25    0.180625
3   Rome      1996-02-26    0.149749
4   Rome      1996-02-27    0.121288
```

I use `attack_probability_df.loc[attack_probability_df.date == date].loc[attack_probability_df.city == city]["attack probability"]` to extract `attack probability` by needed date and city, but my code returns this:

```
2345    0.18593
Name: attack probability, dtype: float64
```

instead of numeric value. How can I extract the value itself?

Comment: I wish to get attack probability value for given city and date

Comment: You have it.  You can use that value in computations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `.values[0]` on the end to get the `attack_probability`.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer by cmauck10 answers the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74437377/7789963) keeping the syntax suggested in the question.

Here is an another way (known as [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)) to get `attack_probability` without using [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

`df`:

```
   city        date  attack probability
0  Rome  1996-02-23            0.163317
1  Rome  1996-02-24            0.219221
2  Rome  1996-02-25            0.180625
3  Rome  1996-02-26            0.149749
4  Rome  1996-02-27            0.121288
```

Query:

```
c = "Rome"
d = "1996-02-25"
```

Solution:

```
print(df[(df['city'] == c) & (df['date'] == d)]["attack probability"].values[0])
```

which gives `0.180625`.